# check if points are present in polygons

Tags: python, gis, polygon, geopandas

I have two GeoDataFrames - one consisting of polygons, one consisting of points. I want to check if each point is present in any of the polygons.

The two GeoDataFrames look like this:

polygon geodataframe:

```
0   (POLYGON ((533118.99658534 6115989.99792342, 5...
1   (POLYGON ((535928.18558342 6116449.18215799, 5...
2   (POLYGON ((582344.60979557 6360821.37795918, 5...
3   (POLYGON ((565979.84052407 6351844.48030166, 5...
4   (POLYGON ((563311.9635688 6349444.93872141, 56...
```

point geodataframe:

```
0   POINT (519065.09 6122281.5)
1   POINT (511065.09 6142281.5)
2   POINT (520065.09 6202281.5)
3   POINT (529065.09 6292281.5)
4   POINT (543065.09 6432281.5)
```

I have tried

```
pointFrame['check'] = 'no'
for pt in pointFrame:
    point = pt
    for poly in polyFrame:
        polygon = poly
        if pointFrame[pt]['check'] == 'no':
            if polygon.contains(point) == True:
                pointFrame['check'] = 'yes'
            else: pass
        else: pass
```

I hope to get a point GeoDataFrame that looks something like this:

```
0   POINT (519065.09 6122281.5)   'yes'
1   POINT (511065.09 6142281.5)   'no'
2   POINT (520065.09 6202281.5)   'no'
3   POINT (529065.09 6292281.5)   'yes'
4   POINT (543065.09 6432281.5)   'yes'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction code wise?

Comment: You can do a spatial join http://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html and then a `groupby` and `any`.

Comment: How big your dataframes are? If small or you don't mind performance, you can do `union = polyFrame.geometry.unary_union` and then `pointFrame.intersects(union)`.